# How to debug in sql(Oracle)

Tags: sql

I am writing a long SQL query and I'm getting incorrect output fields. How do I debug this query?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the query you are attempting and the output you are receiving. You may also want to let us know what output you were expecting that you did not receive.

Comment: Is the question `How do I find my errors?` or `How can I step through a query line by line like java or C# in a debugger?`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no right answer to this question. I think deep down you know that.

When I have something complicated break it down to uncomplicated pieces. Once you are comfortable with these pieces then one by one start to put this complicated thing back together again. The main point is keep breaking complicated things into more and more simple things. I am not embarrassed to say I have broken things down to select sysdate from dual and then start to build back up!

Good Luck.